# High Assets Loading Time

Tags: android, libgdx, android-5.0-lollipop, nexus-4

I just published my game on play store and some of my friends complain me about huge loading time more than **1 min (more than 1000 frames)** in some **lollipop device (nexus 4 ,OS 5.0)**.Usually it take **5-10 (180 frames approx)** seconds to load all assets even devices with Single-core 1.0 GHz processor.

I am loading all assets using asset manager class.

The problem is with loading Mp3 sound files.There are about 52 sounds,2 music files.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps consider only loading what you need instead of everything. But we'd need more specifics about total assets to better be able to help you.

Comment: my all assets took less than 9mb in memory.so i think it gud to load all assets in start and only in few devices

Answer (score 1):

I've never personally used AssetsManager, but I can reccomend various other techniques to help you out:

> Assets are stored in your Android project's assets directory and will be packaged with your APK automatically when you deploy your application. No other application can access these files.
>
> Files can also be stored on the internal storage, where they are readable and writable. Each installed application has a dedicated internal storage directory. This directory is again only accessible by that application. One can think of this storage as a private working area for the application.

Normal practice for me would be to create different Handlers, such as soundHandler, spriteHandler, animationHandler etc. You can seperate the calls out evenly and load what you need from each class. It might help adding a splash screen (if you don't have one already) it would be highly useful to load that over your runtime assets loading. This will provide the 'illusion' the assets are loading quickly but a screen is just layering.

Example:

```
    public void create () {
            batcher = new SpriteBatch();
            SettingsHandler.load();
            AssetsHandler.load();
            SoundHandler.load();
            setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(this));
    }
```

I would also reccomend using Texture Atlases created by [Texture Packer GUI](https://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker). You're able to load the images from a .txt files rather than an image file. This will give you the 'atlas' on the spritesheet reading in strings is always preferable.

Example atlas file:

```
gui.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest, Nearest
repeat: none
drone1
  rotate: false
  xy: 274, 2
  size: 176, 66
  orig: 176, 66
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
drone2
  rotate: false
  xy: 2, 91
  size: 150, 66
  orig: 150, 66
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Example Implementation of Texture Atlases:

```
    int droneIndex = 1;
    TextureRegion[] drones = new TextureRegion[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < drones.length; i++) 
    {
        drones[i] = gui.findRegion(("drone" + droneIndex));
    }
    droneFly = new AnimationHandler(0.2f, drones);
```

I would reccomend following [LibGdx's Advice.](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling) and manipulate the files in realtime when being loaded from the SD or Assets folder and allocate your memory use accordingly. Thats not all you can do.

What would be reccomended? [How to decrease loading time of all Assets in libgdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17488012/how-to-decrease-loading-time-of-all-assets-in-libgdx) offers a great answer. Creating a form of splash screen but for your main GUI, to make it look like the Assets are loaded but all you are doing is rendering a screen over your assets loading at runtime. Emphasize on the example given above but with a full code example.

I would also reccomend looking into the coding principle "DRY" (Don't repeat Yourself). This is a great principle if you wish to be suffecient with what you write in regards to classification of objects. Loading time isn't always about what you can do with your assets. It's about what you do with your code. 
Further Reading [here](http://Principle%20-%20Don't%20Repeat%20Yourself%20%20%20%20%20%20A%20basic%20strategy%20for%20reducing%20complexity%20to%20managable%20units%20is%20to%20divide%20a%20system%20into%20pieces.), [here](http://pixelscientists.com/blog/posts/convenient-game-architecture-with-libgdx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: I am using texture atlas.I don't know why it is problem on few devices only..?

Comment: You'll need to set a few break points and log your data to find out what the problem is. You can use a spritebatch derative by founding out how many render calls you've made http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html, if it's too many consolidate it all.

Comment: The problem is due to mp3 sound files.It takes lot of time in loading.

Comment: i am loading sound using assets manager and i am disposing assets man. in dispose method of ApplicationListerer class

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same problem,
had about 10 images to load (3 mb total, loading time about 8 sec).
I Just cut down the total size to 2 mb total by compressing the images, and saved upto 3-4 seconds.
Also make sure to dispose the assets once completed.

Have a try with this and test the result.

Comment: I think compressing the images reduces quality considerably. What compression method/technique i should use?

Comment: The problem is due to sound files.Any suggestions.

Comment: are you disposing your sounds when the app closes inside the super classes dispose method? and are you storing your sounds internally? so that you're calling them with the Gdx.files.internal method?

Comment: i am loading sound using assets manager and i am disposing assets manager in dispose method of ApplicationListerer class.Any suggestion